# How to: setup Intel rapid start

Tags: partitioning, intel, bios

A short How TO guide, on how to setup intel rapid start on your laptop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this is a short guide, since I just got it working :)

Intel rapid start makes the laptop go into deep sleep after X(defined in bios) mins/hours. It will save you some battery life, if you leave your laptop in sleep for a long time. Read about it here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/what-is-intel-rapid-start-technology

Make sure your laptop supports it (check BIOS) and you have UEFI + GPT partition table. (thats what worked for me at least)

Here how I did it:

- Make sure you have 4/8GB (same as your RAM) or whatever left as free storage. (or or shrink your /home partition. Depends on your setup) I uded gparted live usb for this.
- Install gdisk and do the following:

  - sudo gdisk /dev/sdX (x being a,b,c whatever)
  - type p to print partiton table, you should see something like 8GB
    free.
  - type n, to create a new partition. If you only have like 8GB space
    free, just type enter until you see info about Hex code or GUID.
  - Enter D3BFE2DE-3DAF-11DF-BA40-E3A556D89593 as a Hex code or GUID.
  - Finish with w and Y to write it to disk.
- Reboot into bios, activate Intel rapid start and set how many hours
  you think is okay. I use 1 hour.

You can use 1 min setup for testing. It worked for me, hope it works for you :)

ALSO: Please note you might need to patch your kernel. See this: https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/423494/ You should be able to google how to patch ubuntu kernel.

Comment: The link to the intel guide is broken. Maybe it would be nice to fix this or to copy the info that is there onto here